# SQL Compare one value to a set of data

Tags: sql, oracle

Having the following structure

[image: Data Structure]

I'm trying to look for cases where **BCA_Category** is contained in possible values from **Offering_Cust_Cat** column, noting that each **BPI_ID** is enumerating every possible **Offering_Cust_Cat** value for it, so we should take **BPI_ID** as key for the search.

I have created the following query to group all data and generated one final column **indicator** to notice where the **BCA_Category** is matching to **Offering_Cust_Cat** value, however, it is not being compared to all the possible values yet.

```
select no.object_id bpi_id, no.name bpi_name, nr.reference offering, nr2.reference offering_cust_cat, nr3.reference bca, nr4.reference bca_category,
case when nr4.reference in nr2.reference then 'BCA Category is same'
ELSE 'BCA category is not same'
END as indicator
from nc_objects no
inner join nc_references nr on nr.object_id = no.object_id and nr.attr_id = 9126099920013458621 /* Product Offering */
inner join nc_references nr2 on nr.reference = nr2.object_id and nr2.attr_id = 9132199382713895167 /* Customer Category */
inner join nc_references nr3 on nr3.object_id = no.object_id and nr3.attr_id =  9149183862513001518 /* CA of Associated Product */
inner join nc_references nr4 on nr4.object_id = nr3.reference and nr4.attr_id = 7030151465013152898 /* Customer Category */
where no.object_type_id = 9126083628313449001 /* Business Product Instance */
```

Comment: when nr4.reference in nr2.reference then 'BCA Category is same' - does not look OK. It could be nr4.reference = nr2.reference or nr2.reference like '%'|| nr4.reference||'%'. And uppercase/lowercase may also matter. But the in operator is to be used for in (... list of values ...) or in (select ...)

Comment: From site [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc**.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)